# Watson Conversation Optional Response Type with context variable is possible?

Tags: watson-conversation

At some point in my Dialog, I want to define a response type optional, and put inside a context variable that conforms with user choice, something like this:

```
    "options": [
          {
            "label": "Choice 1",
            "value": {
              "input": {
                "text": "Choice text 1"
              },
              "context": {
                  "choice_variable1": "123"
              }
            }
          }
    ]
```

It is possible? I tried and nothing happened. I want to use this to redirect to more complex intents and responses...

Comment: Do you have any question?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by putting `SpEL` expression directly to the output text like this:

```
    "options": [
          {
            "label": "Choice 1",
            "value": {
              "input": {
                "text": "Choice text 1 <?context.addProperty('choice_variable1',123)?>"
              }
            }
          }
    ]
```